# Methods to prevent brute force & DoS attacks- PHP & Apache

Tags: php, apache, memcached

Solutions to preventing DoS and brute force attacks on the server and application level are innumerable-not to mention a little confusing. I am taking my first few steps to hardening a few of my php applications, and would like to know the best practices for preventing brute force/dictionary attacks on user forms, for example, keeping in mind that I already use captcha:)

And what is the best practice for server level prevention of DoS attacks?

Experimental implementations are welcome for discussion

My environment is:

- php 5.2
- apache 2x
- Custom Framework

Note: Memcached is due for implementation, and Floodcontrol is one method I have yet to fiddle around with --- any elaboration on this is welcome, too.

Comment: You will hardly be able to defend against DoS attacks using PHP. The only real defense against (D)DoS is to either throw enough iron at the incoming traffic to cope with it, or to have a high-powered appliance in front of your web server that can filter known bogus requests (tricky). The other questions are more interesting though...

Comment: @deceze Noted! And what appliance, specifically, are you referring to?

Comment: Might be interesting questions, but they don't belong on stackoverflow. Please read the FAQ to see what kind of questions are allowed here. Open-ended discussion-type questions are explicitly not allowed, and general questions about abstract programming concepts belong on programmers.stackexchange.com. I'd recommend refining your question to ask something more specific, and asking it on programmers stackexchange.

Comment: @BenLee Fair enough, Mr. Lee!

Comment: @DudeSolutions, there's also http://security.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Here are some related questions: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/241/how-can-a-software-application-defend-against-dos-or-ddos http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/114/what-techniques-do-advanced-firewalls-use-to-protect-againt-dos-ddos http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4667/how-do-dos-ddos-work

Comment: @BenLee This network is overwhelmingly vast. Thanks for the heads up!